# OpenCV Initializing Camera: Unknown query to pre-built opencv files

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2019, cmake-gui

I downloaded the OpenCV repository from github and used CMake (GUI) and Visual Studio to build it.

When I run the generic code example (C++) for opening the camera, when calling cap.open(0,0), I get the below message in the command prompt.

Does anyone know why/where the call comes from for trying to access the files I used during the CMake process (essentially the github files):

```
[ INFO:0] global E:\...\opencv-master\modules\videoio\src\videoio_registry.cpp (191) cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(7, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940)

[ INFO:0] global E:\...\opencv-master\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (370) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER

[ INFO:0] global E:\...\opencv-master\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (175) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\OpenCV\x64\vc16\bin\opencv_videoio_gstreamer440_64d.dll => FAILED

[ INFO:0] global E:\...\opencv-master\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (175) cv::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_gstreamer440_64d.dll => FAILED
```

P.S.: The camera opens successfully. I just don't know why it is first querying these files(even after I deleted them). The installation that was built via Virtual Studio is contained in a separate folder and the paths to the VC++ Directories and the lib folder is set to this installation directory.

Comment: It seems your program depends on the DLL file, but the loader cannot find it at run-time. Ensure this DLL file actually exists, and that the path to the DLL is present in your `Path` environment variable, or that these DLLs are located in the *same* directory as your executable.

Comment: `GSTREAMER(990)` backend is activated dynamically so it will look for it in the `lib` directory (`C:\OpenCV\x64\vc16\bin\ ` in your case). If you want it built-in you can activate it with CMake option `-DWITH_GSTREAMER=ON`. There is also a last "d" in the DLL name: verify if you compiled everything in debug or release.